# Converting to svf format using Model Derivative API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge

I want to try my rvt file converted to svf file format using your "Model Derivative API". I need to keep this in my local. I'm using your API for this, but I'm getting an error like this  "diagnostic" : "Invalid 'design' parameter."

Is this error due to the "urn" part? If so, what should I enter in the "urn" parameter and how do I get the svf zip file.

I would be very happy if you tell me what to do about this API. Since I am new to API and Forge API, I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're converting urn to to a Base64-encoded URN , use this tool for coversion, **Please share the screenshot of the error.**

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-file4viewer/task2-upload_source_file_to_oss/#step-3-convert-the-assembly-file-urn-to-a-base64-encoded-urn

You are looking forward to using the model derivative APIs. Please go through https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-file4viewer/task1-authenticate/ to perform authentication & get access token.

Steps to start-

1. Create an app on forge portal with model derivative APIs (follow this) .Get the client id and  client secret.
2. Install software Postman or Insomnia. Here is a set of Postman collection which you may import     , https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-tutorial-postman
3. Perform authentication and obtain an access token. So, if you want the access token, you will have to go through 2legged Authentication https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v1/tutorials/get-2-legged-token/
4. Perform steps 2 - 4(https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-file4viewer/task2-upload_source_file_to_oss/)  which are upload source to oss, translate & display .

About saving SVF to local-

As you know, Forge is a cloud development platform , a set of web service APIs you can use to build innovative, cloud-powered applications. So, the extraction of SVF in local system is not officially supported by Autodesk. You might want to go through this extractor at your own risk https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io , https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs.